# Specific users cannot open Excel 2010 on Windows server 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 installation with multiple users. They are mostly identical and serve the same purpose - and are therefore members of the same groups (administrators included).

Whenever these users try to open Excel - directly or by a file - they recieve the error:

`Windows cannot access the specified path or file. you may not have the appropriate permissions`.

This is not a new installations and those users could open Excel before - and some users still can. No change has taken place on the server.

Permissions for these users exist both on the Excel executable and the files they try to open.

Is there any way I can solve this without reinstalling Excel or recreating the users? I'd like to minimise downtime as much as possible.

Thanks!

UPDATE: per suggestions below, I tried disabling the antivirus and checking for unusual entries with the process monitor, but the issue remains. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Which is the problem? That some users **can** or **cannot** open Excel?

Comment: Do you have a third-party antivirus? If yes, try to disable it temporarily. You could also find the error by monitoring this with the [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), filtering for failing file operations.

Comment: Thank you both for your excellent suggestions - to clarify, the problem is that some users **cannot** open Excel. I couldn't see any failed file operations (perhaps I'm not using ProcMon right), and disabling the antivirus did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to post online the ProcMon log `.pml` with Dropbox or OneDrive or such (without filters)?

Comment: I'm afraid not - sorry!